# How to position spans in a header

Tags: html, css

so I have a header and three spans inside of it home, search and logout what if I want to make the "home" button sticked to the left border and to make "search" beside the "home" with just a 5px margin and "logout" sticked to the right border and this is the code I have rn

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <span class="first"> home </span>
    <span class="second"> search </span>
    <span class="third"> logout </span>
  </header>
</body>
</html>




css:



body {
    margin: 0;
}

header {
    border: 5px solid green;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
}

span {
    margin: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without altering the HTML, you can use the margin-left: auto setting on the element you want to place to the right, keeping the flex setting as it currently is.

You will want to set margins to what you require as I'm not absolutely sure what you want.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    header {
      border: 5px solid green;
      margin: 0;
      display: flex;
    }
    
    .second {
      margin-left: 5px;
    }
    
    .third {
      margin-left: auto;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <header class="main">
    <span class="first">
        Home
      </span>
    <span class="second">
        Search
      </span>
    <span class="third">
        Logout
      </span>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```